# Dual booting Ubuntu 14 and WIN 8.1 - Windows takes over

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8, usb-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 from an official web page and installed it as instructed by many different sites on a pre-installed Win 8.1 VAIO laptop.

I was able to boot to Ubuntu and play around, even without the installation usb plugged in, but once I switched to Windows, it took over the boot, and from then on I had no way to boot to Ubuntu.

I looked at Windows' system properties and saw that under "default operating system" there was only Windows.

Therefore, I tried to reinstall. The partition I had allocated was still there, but once again, after a seemingly smooth installation process, and being able to load the OS and do actual stuff like installing packages and so on, loading up Windows was the end of the road for Ubuntu.

In both cases I made sure I was installing Ubuntu on the main hard drive and not some other removable media, and also I made sure I didn't choose the "try Ubuntu" option.

What could I have done incorrectly and how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot, and I apologize if this is a duplicate - I couldn't find any reference to this type of problem.

Comment: Do you have 'Fast Boot' enabled in your BIOS settings? If yes, disable it. Btw. there's no need to reinstall Ubuntu every time. The only thing that is being broken by Windows is Ubuntu's boot loader. You can attempt to fix this using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Several alternative fixes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Windows and open a Console with Administrative Rights.
Once in, you just have to copy this command :

```
 bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Reboot and GNU grub should come up.

Comment: That's strange - I am the only user and have administrative rights, but running the command didn't work, the reply was: The boot configuration data store could not be opened. Access is denied. Maybe worth mentioning: I ran it on the cmd, I suppose that's what you meant by console, right?

Comment: @Yoni cmd with admin permission not just cmd. After you logged in to windows press win key+x then hit "a" on the keyboard. This way a cmd with admin permission is opened. Or you can search for cmd in windows and right click on it and run it as admin.